# get file path after getting documents path

Tags: ios, swift, filepath

I get documents path by creat

```
func docPath() -> String {
  let documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        return documentPaths[0]
}
```

Now, I would like to get a file path, that file is located under document path. I tried:

```
let documentPath = docPath()
let filePath = documentPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myFile")
```

But I get error: `Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByAppendingPathComponent'`

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has removed the path manipulating API from `String`.

Two solutions:

- Bridge cast `String` to `NSString`

  ```
  let filePath = (documentPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("myFile")
  ```
- Use the `URL` related API (recommended)

  ```
  func docURL() -> URL {
      return try! FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
  }

  let documentURL = docURL()
  let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("myFile")
  ```

The code is Swift 3+.

Comment: `documentURL.appendingPathComponent` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You have try this too. U have to convert to URL.

```
let documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)

let documentpath : URL =  URL(fileURLWithPath: documentPaths[0])
let filePath = documentpath.appendingPathComponent("myfile")
```